# Trained Neural Network model in C?

Tags: neural-network, caffe, darknet, ansi-c

I am not an expert in machine learning and neural networks, at the computational intelligence field in general but I am looking to find a Neural Network model which is written in ANSI C language.

What I wish to do with the classifier is to train it and then use it as a benchmark for experimental reasons along with its weights. In general the file that I am looking is built like this:

```
#include <.....>

/* -- Global Variables -- */ 

double weight_layer_a_neuron_1 = ... ;
double weight_layer_a_neuron_2 = ... ;
..
..
..
double weight_layer_n_neuron_n = ... ;

/* ---------------------- */

/* 
 * Neural Network Model Code Here
 */
```

The reason that I am looking for this specific architecture is that I need to cross-compile it in another system and C is one of the few options.

I have looked online for **DarkNet** and **caffee** libraries if they support an option like that, to "export" the model in a C file but as I expected I didn't find anything. Are there any options available for my case? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: No framework that I'm aware of allows to export a trained model as a C file. This would also be very inconvenient. I guess you'll have to write your own converter or change approach.

Comment: Thanks. I found genann ( https://github.com/codeplea/genann ) library though which might be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ANSWER]

Although none of the frameworks mentioned above provides the network file in C you can use the [codeplea's genann](https://github.com/codeplea/genann) library which provides a delicate and beautiful way to create / train / store / load your neural network. It also provides various training methods.

There is not an automatic way to generate and create a network as fast as Darknet and Caffe suggest but with a little effort and based on the examples provided by the author you can create your nn quite easily.